# Can a BigInteger be truncated to an i32 in Rust?

Tags: rust, biginteger

In Java, `intValue()` gives back a truncated portion of the `BigInteger` instance. I wrote a similar program in Rust but it appears not to truncate:

```
extern crate num;

use num::bigint::{BigInt, RandBigInt};
use num::ToPrimitive;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    truncate_num(
        BigInt::parse_bytes(b"423445324324324324234324", 10).unwrap(),
        BigInt::parse_bytes(b"22447", 10).unwrap(),
    );
}

fn truncate_num(num1: BigInt, num2: BigInt) -> i32 {
    println!("Truncation of {} is {:?}.", num1, num1.to_i32());
    println!("Truncation of {} is {:?}.", num2, num2.to_i32());
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get from this is

```
Hello, world!
Truncation of 423445324324324324234324 is None.
Truncation of 22447 is Some(22447).
```

How can I achieve this in Rust? Should I try a conversion to `String` and then truncate manually? This would be my last resort.

Comment: What should be a "truncation" of a big int fitting into an i32 ? You should probably check whether the Option contains a value and use it only in that case.

Comment: Why do you want this feature ???

Comment: What do you want exactly? Please explain the expected result with different cases and your usecase. Otherwise, your question is too broad.

Comment: Specifically, Java specifies on [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue()): _"This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigInteger is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned."_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Java returned value in case of not fitting value is implementation leaking and makes no functional sense. This should not be reproduced in rust.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I posted my comment so people would know what the equivalent behaviour would need to be. Given the behaviour is explicitly defined to behave similar as what happens when casting a long to int, it is not "implementation leaking", it was a deliberate design choice. And if you don't want this type of behavior, you can use [`intValueExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValueExact()) which will throw an exception if the value is out of range for an int.

Comment: I don't know Rust, but if I had to guess, the same behavior could be achieved by using `to_signed_bytes_be` and then taking the last 4 bytes, converting that back to int. It would be a hack, sure, and you'd need to consider if you really need this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java's [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue()) returns the lowest 32 bits of the integer. This could be done by a bitwise-AND operation `x & 0xffffffff`. A [`BigInt` in Rust](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/*/num_bigint/struct.BigInt.html) doesn't support bitwise manipulation, but you could first convert it to a `BigUint` which [supports](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/*/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html#impl-BitAnd%3CBigUint%3E) such operations.

```rust
fn truncate_biguint_to_u32(a: &BigUint) -> u32 {
    use std::u32;
    let mask = BigUint::from(u32::MAX);
    (a & mask).to_u32().unwrap()
}
```

Converting `BigInt` to `BigUint` will be successful only when it is not negative. If the `BigInt` is negative (-x), we could find the lowest 32 bits of its absolute value (x), then negate the result.

```rust
fn truncate_bigint_to_u32(a: &BigInt) -> u32 {
    use num_traits::Signed;

    let was_negative = a.is_negative();
    let abs = a.abs().to_biguint().unwrap();
    let mut truncated = truncate_biguint_to_u32(&abs);
    if was_negative {
        truncated.wrapping_neg()
    } else {
        truncated
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e43befa6456cd5877d6a8b5ebaafdc49&version=nightly&mode=debug)

You may use `truncate_bigint_to_u32(a) as i32` if you need a signed number.

---

There is also a [`to_signed_bytes_le()`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/*/num_bigint/struct.BigInt.html#method.to_signed_bytes_le) method with which you could extract the bytes and decode that into a primitive integer directly:

```rust
fn truncate_bigint_to_u32_slow(a: &BigInt) -> u32 {
    let mut bytes = a.to_signed_bytes_le();
    bytes.resize(4, 0);
    bytes[0] as u32 | (bytes[1] as u32) << 8 | (bytes[2] as u32) << 16 | (bytes[3] as u32) << 24
}
```

This method is extremely slow compared to the above methods and I don't recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks @kennytm. This would be another way of doing what i want if there is no natural truncation. I am switching over from Java to Rust hence contrasting with Java.

Answer (score 4):

There's no natural truncation of a big integer into a smaller one. Either it fits or you have to decide what value you want.

You could do this:

```
println!("Truncation of {} is {:?}.", num1, num1.to_i32().unwrap_or(-1));
```

or

```
println!("Truncation of {} is {:?}.", num1, num1.to_i32().unwrap_or(std::i32::MAX));
```

but your application logic should probably dictate what's the desired behavior when the returned option contains no value.

Comment: Thanks @Denys but i really need the behavior as in Java I would rather not attempt to use `to_i32` at all if it cannot suffice in all the cases. I would anyhow have to use the other logic for the cases when returned option contains no value.